# Swift viewController numberOfRowsInSection issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift, learning from http://www.raywenderlich.com's tutorial..

I have written this controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var totalTextField : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var taxPctSlider : UISlider!
@IBOutlet var taxPctLabel : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var resultsTextView : UITextView!
let tipCalc = TipCalculatorModel(total: 33.25, taxPct: 0.06)
var possibleTips = Dictionary<Int, (tipAmt:Double, total:Double)>()
var sortedKeys:[Int] = []
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.refreshUI()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func refreshUI() {
    totalTextField.text = String(format: "%0.2f", tipCalc.total)
    taxPctSlider.value = Float(tipCalc.taxPct) * 100.0
    taxPctLabel.text = "Tax Percentage (\(Int(taxPctSlider.value))%"
}

@IBAction func calculateTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
    tipCalc.total = Double((totalTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue)
    possibleTips = tipCalc.returnPossibleTips()
    sortedKeys = sorted(Array(possibleTips.keys))
    tableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func taxPercentageChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    tipCalc.taxPct = Double(taxPctSlider.value) / 100
    refreshUI()
}

@IBAction func viewTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    totalTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sortedKeys.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    let tipPct = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    let tipAmt = possibleTips[tipPct]!.tipAmt
    let total = possibleTips[tipPct]!.total

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(tipPct)%:"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(format: "Tip: $%0.2f, Total: $%0.2f", tipAmt, total)
    return cell
}


}
```

when I try to run this application, I get next error:

```
-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

unfortunately, I am new to this programming language and to programming for iphone, so I have no idea how to fix this issue.

I would appreciate your help on this manner

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, your `sortedKeys` array doesn't have any values in it. It's only initialized as an empty array of type `Int`. You have it set to populate only once your `calculateTapped()` method is called. Therefore, `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't return a valid number of rows for your table view because `sortedKeys.count` returns `0`.

Comment: how can I fix this? I tried to write an init function, but it gives me more errors..

Comment: You could have the `numberOfRowsInSection` initially return a static number of cells or if you want it to return your `sortedKeys` array you have to have populate the array with values and not be empty upon load.